# Oracle To Teradata Record Validation

Tags: validation, teradata, database-migration

Project Background:

I am part of data migration project. Data is to be migrated from one platform(oracle) to another platform(teradata). My project requirement is that I have to compare whole data of each table between these two databases. But my problem is that client is not allowing us to create temp table at target database. So unable to use minus query for full data validation at target side.

When table has less data suppose less than 100,000 row. In this case it is easy for me to compare table data using excel(after importing in two different excel and then compare using excel in built compare tool or macro) But when row count is more than 100,000 suppose 10 or 200,000. In this case I am unable to use excel for full data validation.

Project belongs to banking sector so client is not allowing us to use any third party tool for data comparison.

My question is "How do I validate full data between two different database platform without using minus query in data migration project" Please help me in this scenario.

Comment: @Anshu ..instead of exporting entire data why don't you create validation queries like doing group by, min,max,sum and finding the length of the character data etc.This will almost guarantee your data is correct or not.

Comment: Thanks Anwer..but Requirement to do full data validation from source oracle to Teradata staging tables..as soon as Target load completed..Please suggest if any Tool can use or any Linked server can be created between oracle and Teradata..?